# 2D polygon triangulation

Tags: c++, windows, geometry, 2d

The code below is my attempt at triangulation. It outputs the wrong angles (it read a square's angles as 90, 90. 90, 176) and draws the wrong shapes. What am I doing wrong?

```
//use earclipping to generate a list of triangles to draw
std::vector<vec> calcTriDraw(std::vector<vec> poly)
{
    std::vector<double> polyAngles;
    //get angles
    for(unsigned int i = 0;i < poly.size();i++)
    {

        int p1 = i - 1;
        int p2 = i;
        int p3 = i + 1;

        if(p3 > int(poly.size()))
            p3 -= poly.size();
        if(p1 < 0)
            p1 += poly.size();

        //get the angle of from 3 points
        double dx, dy;
        dx = poly[p2].x - poly[p1].x;
        dy = poly[p2].y - poly[p1].y;
        double a = atan2(dy,dx);

        dx = poly[p3].x - poly[p2].x;
        dy = poly[p3].y - poly[p2].y;
        double b = atan2(dy,dx);
        polyAngles.push_back((a-b)*180/PI);
    }
    std::vector<vec> triList;
    for(unsigned int i = 0;i < poly.size() && poly.size() > 2;i++)
    {
        int p1 = i - 1;
        int p2 = i;
        int p3 = i + 1;

        if(p3 > int(poly.size()))
            p3 -= poly.size();
        if(p1 < 0)
            p1 += poly.size();

        if(polyAngles[p2] >= 180)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            triList.push_back(poly[p1]);
            triList.push_back(poly[p2]);
            triList.push_back(poly[p3]);
            poly.erase(poly.begin()+p2);
            std::vector<vec> add = calcTriDraw(poly);
            triList.insert(triList.end(), add.begin(), add.end());
            break;
        }
    }

    return triList;
}
```

Sorry, I don't know why the first few lines aren't getting counted as code.

Comment: Use the tag <pre> around your code to solve the formatting issue. I'm afraid that's all I can help with :)

Comment: Indent your code an extra four spaces for automatic code-formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reduce p3 if it is >= poly.size(), not just >.

Edit: python code to test

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import math
p = ((0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0))
for i in xrange(4):
   p1 = (i + 3) % 4
   p2 = i
   p3 = (i + 1) % 4
   a = math.atan2(p[p2][1] - p[p1][1], p[p2][0] - p[p1][0])
   b = math.atan2(p[p3][1] - p[p2][1], p[p3][0] - p[p2][0])
   print (a-b)*180/math.pi
```

And to run it:

```
$ ./tmp.py 
90.0
90.0
90.0
-270.0
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see that, but it didn't seem to do anything :(

Answer (score 0):

You don't evaluate angles correctly.

Look at the snippet from your code, and to this picture.

In the picture there are two different situations.
The first one, when the polygon is above the points P1, P2, P3 (then angle = 135 degrees), and the second situation when it is under these points (then angle = 225 degrees), but your code will evaluate the same angle in both situations.

```
    //get the angle of from 3 points
    double dx, dy;
    dx = poly[p2].x - poly[p1].x;
    dy = poly[p2].y - poly[p1].y;
    double a = atan2(dy,dx);

    dx = poly[p3].x - poly[p2].x;
    dy = poly[p3].y - poly[p2].y;
    double b = atan2(dy,dx);
    polyAngles.push_back((a-b)*180/PI);
```

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/28a3a66573.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/28a3a66573.png)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but the poly parameter is an array of verts that make up the perimeter of the polygon. Why is P2 inside it?

Comment: I think I see what you mean, but how do I fix that?

Comment: Your solution has one more problem. As I understood, you cut off a triangle, if angle is less than 180 degrees, but it is incorrect, cause the cutting line can intersect polygon. I think the straightforward solution is, first, divide your polygon to convex polygons, and then trivially triangulating each.